# SQL Server 2012 New Server - More Physical Cores or Faster CPU

Tags: sql-server, sockets

I am configuring a new Dell server to run SQLServer 2012 Enterprise. I have a option to purchase a server that has 12 cores per physical socket (CPU) at 2.7Ghz or a server having 8 cores per CPU at 3.3GHz. I will hae 2 physical sockets (CPUS)
The server runs both OLTP and OLAP processing. What would give me the best performance for SQL?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: This isn't the right web site to ask this question, as only you can determine the answer. A faster CPU will make an individual task finish faster, while more CPUs will allow more tasks to run simultaneously. We don't know which one is more important for your workload, nor can we try it out for you.

Comment: @Gabe true, but an answer can show how to find the solution in any similar situation.

Comment: @usr: OK, well in that case he should ask his question on serverfault.com, as this question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: On top,for a sql server, CPU is rarely limiting.

Answer (score 2):

For **licensing reasons** your company will likely prefer less, faster CPUs as costs rise linearly with the number of cores. A license costs >10x as much as a core.

Comparing cycles per seconds:

```
2.7*12=32.4 //more
3.3*8=26.4
```

The 12-core variant seems far superior. Note, that some workloads do not scale linearly with the number of cores. They scale less. This might turn performance in favor of the CPU with less cores. You'd need to measure with a realistic workload. Do not make the mistake of measuring a toy workload.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your workload.  If you expect to be calculation heavy (i.e. CPU intensive) or to be dealing with large datasets.

Generally it's easier for cores on a single CPU die to share cache and memory resources.  This, of course, depends on specifically which CPU make/model you are talking about.  Some architectures have the memory controller on the die (Intel i7 and AMD Athlon 64, for example).  This makes for less memory latency, but more overhead when sharing memory between CPUs.  Some architectures have a controller separate from the die (northbridge).  However, the higher clock cycles might make-up for any memory context overhead.

So, if you're expecting a more memory intensive workload, go with fewer CPU sockets and more cores (and more memory).  If you're expecting a more CPU intensive workload, go with higher clock cycles.

This is going to depend largely on your hardware platform, so your mileage may vary.  Honestly, I find that more memory and faster disks make a much larger impact than CPU anyway.

Unfortunately, the only way to really know is to test both against real-world workloads and measure the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the question, but the answer is probably more ram. Any change you can push for that?